# Python Selenium ElementNotInteractableException for ui-dialog element

Tags: python, selenium, automation

I am trying to automate filling in my time sheet using Selenium in python. I get to the point where I click submit and then a dialog box pops up asking if I am sure I want to submit. I then tried this initially:

```
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//button[@class='btn btn-sm btn-primary']").click()
```

But get ElementNotInteractableException. No matter what I try I cannot interact with that dialog box. I have tried expected conditions, switch_to and trying to Tab to the box. But to no avail.

Here is the html of the element:

```
<div class="ui-dialog ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-draggable ui-resizable" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="ui-dialog-title-divConfirmST" style="z-index: 1002; outline: 0px; position: absolute; height: auto; width: 450px; top: 350.148px; left: 449px;"><div class="ui-dialog-titlebar ui-widget-header ui-helper-clearfix"><h2 class="ui-dialog-title" id="ui-dialog-title-divConfirmST"><span><img src="../../Content/GUIFrameWork/images/icons/confirmation.png" align="absmiddle" style="margin:0px 5px 0px 0px"></span> Submit Timesheet Confirmation</h2><a href="#" class="ui-dialog-titlebar-close" role="button" aria-label="close"><span class="icon icon-close"></span></a></div><div id="divConfirmST" style="width: auto; min-height: 0px; height: 0px;" wfd-invisible="true" class="ui-dialog-content ui-widget-content" scrolltop="0" scrollleft="0">
                <div class="popup-bg personal-info">
                    <table>
                        <tbody><tr>
                            <td height="30">
                                <span id="DefaultContent_LblSubmitTSConfirmation">Are you sure you want to submit this Timesheet?</span>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody></table>
                </div>
            </div><div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-n" style="z-index: 1000;"></div><div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-e" style="z-index: 1000;"></div><div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-s" style="z-index: 1000;"></div><div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-w" style="z-index: 1000;"></div><div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-se ui-icon ui-icon-gripsmall-diagonal-se ui-icon-grip-diagonal-se" style="z-index: 1000;"></div><div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-sw" style="z-index: 1000;"></div><div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-ne" style="z-index: 1000;"></div><div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-nw" style="z-index: 1000;"></div><div class="ui-dialog-buttonpane ui-widget-content ui-helper-clearfix"><div class="ui-dialog-buttonset"><button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary"><span class="icon-checkmark5"></span> Yes</button><button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-danger"><span class="icon-cancel5"></span> No</button></div></div></div>
```

Here is some of what I have tried:

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(ec.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH,"//div[@class='ui-dialog ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-draggable ui-resizable']")))

webElement = driver.find_element("xpath", "//button[@class='btn btn-sm btn-primary']")
webElement.send_keys(Keys.TAB)
webElement.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)

driver.switch_to.default_content()

WebDriverWait(driver, wait).until(
    ec.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//button[@class='btn btn-sm btn-primary']"))).click()

driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//div[@class='ui-dialog ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-draggable ui-resizable']").send_keys(Keys.TAB)
```

I wish I could list everything I have tried but the list is massive. I would very much appreciate any help.

Comment: Have you checked to see if that it's a unique xpath.

Comment: yes pretty sure. none of the elements of that popup are interactable either